# how to make the input accepts arabic in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user input to be in arabic language, I understand I need a unicode but how to assign a unicode to an input

When I set a string in arabic, I do this `x = u"السلام عليكم"` but I tried to do the same when making the input

```
user_input = input(u"اكتب الجملة: ")
```

I expected output to be in Arabic, but I get weird characters

Here is a full screen shot
[The weird characters i get during typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZwP.png)

Comment: $ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = input()  <RET>
السلام عليكم  <RET>
>>> a <RET>
'السلام عليكم'
>>>

if i just do this it works for me, in python3 default is unicode

Comment: What does "But I get symbols" mean? Characters are symbols so you are saying "but it works as intended". Please specify exactly what is your expected output and what do you get instead. On my computer your code, once you remove the call to `u`, works fine. Maybe your terminal does not have the correct font/encoding?

Comment: Ok, so I have two points of confusion instead. Firstly, `u(...)` is an error, but second, you shouldn't need to be marking this string as unicode in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
user_input = input("اكتب الجملة: ")
```

Python 3.X assume UTF-8 is the default source encoding (see PEP 3120 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/).

Comment: If the OP is using Python 3, `str` is useless as input returns a string already. If he is using Python 2, he should use `raw_input`, as any text in arabic will lead to an error when `input` tries to `eval` it.

Comment: Yes true, I thought it was int